# Angular receive an object and fill it in the page

Tags: java, angularjs

Hi friends I have a problem that should be easy to fix but I can't find a solution, I want to fill some information of a object inside a class that come from the AjaxController and need to go back to Ajax. But all this things need to happen in the website.

the class is:

```
public class ContractSummary {

private String defaultSaId;
private Map<String, Contract> saIdMap;
private CustomerInformation customer;
```

So the information inside CustomerInformation is something like `String name, String address ...` and the map is generate automatically.

So the UI when receive the object I want to fill the CustomerInformation. I do something like this:

```
$scope.addCustomer = function() {
  if ($scope.customerName && $scope.customerAddressOne && $scope.customerCity && $scope.customerCountry) {
    $scope.invalidCustomer = false;
    $scope.validCustomer = true;
    $scope.requestView.customerOrgSiteName = $scope.customerName;
    $scope.requestView.customerOrgSiteAddress = $scope.customerAddressOne;
    $scope.requestView.customerOrgSiteCity = $scope.customerCity;
    $scope.requestView.customerOrgSiteCountry = $scope.customerCountry;
    $scope.requestView.customerOrgSiteAddress = $scope.requestView.customerOrgSiteAddress + " " + $scope.customerAddressTwo;
    $scope.requestView.customerOrgSiteState = $scope.customerState;

    // Add Information in the
    // ContractSummary

    $scope.contracSummary.customer.name = $scope.customerName;
    $scope.contracSummary.customer.address = $scope.customerAddressOne;
    $scope.contracSummary.customer.addressTwo = $scope.customerAddressTwo;
    $scope.contracSummary.customer.city = $scope.customerCity;
    $scope.contracSummary.customer.state = $scope.customerState;
    $scope.contracSummary.customer.country = $scope.customerCountry;
    $scope.contracSummary.customer.postCode = $scope.customerPostCode;
  } else {
    $scope.invalidCustomer = true;
    $scope.validCustomer = false;
  }
};
```

When I sent back the object contracSummary to the Ajax receive a null in the customer. And I can't see how this isn't working. Any Idea about it?

Thanks!

Comment: What isn't working? What is it doing? What do you want it to do? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I want to return the customer information. But must to return in the same class. And "$scope.contracSummary.customer.name = $scope.customerName;" isnt do what I expected.